How to specify aggregation options (allowDiskUse:true) through Data API (over REST calls) offered by MongoDB Atlas
How to specify aggregation options (allowDiskUse:true) while making aggregation query through Data API (over REST calls) offered by MongoDB  Atlas?
I looked at the documentation here, but could not find a way.
I need to specify this because I am getting QueryExceededMemoryLimitNoDiskUseAllowed error when I make aggregation query.
